# Missing object when using @SerializedName with Retrofit call

Tags: android, api, serialization, retrofit2

I'm developing an Android app which connects to a Springboot server.

The app (using okhttp3 and retrofit) calls the server which returns an array list in an object (Photo Response) below.

The list is populating but the object MediaContentGroup does not populate in any photo object even though the fields of id and title do.

I've debugged through my server to ensure that I am using the correct object names when using @SerializedName.

I'm pretty new to Android development and using springboot, so if anyone could help me to understand why the MediaContentGroup object is always null, I would really appreciate it.

Is there any possible way I've set it to only accept Strings??

Thanks

```
public class PhotoResponse {

    @SerializedName("photoFeed")
    @Expose
    private PhotoFeed photoFeed;

    public PhotoFeed getPhotoFeed() {
        return photoFeed;
    }
}

public class PhotoFeed {

    @SerializedName("photoList")
    @Expose
    private List<Photo> photoList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Photo> getPhotoList() {
        return photoList;
    }
}

public class Photo {
    public final static int HD_720_WIDTH = 1280;
    public final static int HD_720_HEIGHT = 720;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("mediaContentGroup")
    @Expose
    private MediaContentGroup mediaContentGroup;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setMediaContentGroup(MediaContentGroup mediaContentGroup){
        this.mediaContentGroup = mediaContentGroup;
    }

    public MediaContentGroup getMediaContentGroup(){
        return this.mediaContentGroup;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mediaContentGroup.getImages().get(0).getUrl();
    }

    public String getThumbUrl() {
        return mediaContentGroup.getThumbnails().get(0).getUrl();
    }
}

public class MediaContentGroup {

    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    public List<MediaContent> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setImages(List<MediaContent> images){ this.images = images;}

    public List<MediaContent> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    @SerializedName("thumbnails")
    @Expose
    public List<Thumbnail> thumbnails = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setThumbnails(List<Thumbnail> thumbnails){ this.thumbnails = thumbnails;}

    public List<Thumbnail> getThumbnails() {
        return thumbnails;
    }
}

public class Thumbnail {

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the accompanying JSON?

Comment: I'm using a GSON builder...Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(SERVICE_URL)
                .build();

Comment: Could you show us the JSON response?